# Missing startup banner in Microsoft C++ when running through Java runtime

Tags: java, visual-c++

I ran into a strange issue. I have Java JRE 7 64 bits installed under Windows 7 SP1 64 bits. I also have Visual Studio 2010 IDE with C/C++ compiler installed. I am trying to get the compiler build version by executing the cl.exe command through the Java Runtime Exec.

When I open a cmd.exe shell and execute ..\..\VC\bin\cl.exe in the directory "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE"  I get this output:

Microsoft (R) 32-bit C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 16.00.40219.01 for 80x86
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

usage: cl [ option... ] filename... [ /link linkoption... ]

But when I execute the same command within the Java runtime I get this output:

usage: cl [ option... ] filename... [ /link linkoption... ]

The output doesn't contain the 2 lines startup banner. And I need the startup banner to have the compiler version as well as the build number.

The Java template I am using to execute the command is:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {   
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /d /c chdir /d C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\\Common7\\IDE && ..\\..\\VC\\bin\\cl");   
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));   
        String line = null;   
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {   
            System.out.println(line);   
        }   
    } catch (IOException e) {   
        e.printStackTrace();   
    }   

}
```

I suspect the cl.exe process is able to understand the context into which it was launched and disable the startup banner. Any idea how I can get the startup banner ?

Comment: (Forgot to hit return.) There's more than one place to write output to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `cl.exe` is sending the banner to the error stream. Read `p.GetErrorStream()` to find the banner. You can verify that this is the case on the command prompt by executing the cl like this:

```
cl 2>%userprofile%\Desktop\error.txt
```

Note that the banner doesn't appear, but is routed to your desktop\error.txt.

Comment: Indeed! You are right. Using the redirect operator I can get stderr to stdout. I used this command : cmd /d /c chdir /d C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\\Common7\\IDE && ..\\..\\VC\\bin\\cl 2>&1

Comment: Aha, good work on redirecting standard error to standard output--very nice.